# Extending jQuery is not working...?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not getting how to extend jQuery... I have the following code:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({

    whatever : function () {
        alert('yeah');
    }

});
```

Which should be giving me a `$.whatever` function, no? But when I check it, or try to run it: zilch.

Check out this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/66gpf/

I [checked the docs](http://devdocs.io/jquery/jquery.fn.extend) and it seems good to me... SO, what am I doing wrong??

Comment: you need to use `$('body').html( typeof $('body').whatever );` because it does not add the `whatever` as a property of jQuery static object - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3XKLM/1/

Comment: D'oh! Wanna post that as an answer so I can mark it correct please?

Comment: `jQuery.whatever = function() { alert('yeah') };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jQuery.fn` is a reference to `jQuery.prototype`.  So when you do `jQuery.fn.extend`, you adding a property to the `prototype`, *not* to jQuery itself.  The `whatever` function will exist on all jQuery instances.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    whatever : function () {
        alert('yeah');
    }
});

$('#a_selector').whatever();
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/

P.S. If you want the function to exist as `$.whatever` instead of only on jQuery object instances, then add it to `$` instead of `$.fn`.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery, {
    whatever : function () {
        alert('yeah');
    }
});

$.whatever();
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `$('body').html( typeof $('body').whatever );` because it does not add the whatever as a property of jQuery static object

```
$('body').html(typeof $('body').whatever);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3XKLM/1/)